# Split a column based on string similarity

Tags: r, nlp, string-matching

I've a df as under:

```
+------------+
|    Name    |
+------------+
| ABC 123aa  |
| A BC 456ac |
| AB C 789da |
+------------+
```

I'd want to group the strings that are similar based on the smallest string of the group and split the rest of the string in a new column as under:

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Type  |
+------+-------+
| ABC  | 123aa |
| ABC  | 456ac |
| ABC  | 789da |
+------+-------+
```

I know I could use

```
stringdistmatrix(Name, Name, useNames=T, method="lcs")
```

But I'm still having a hard time to get it into the format I want

Comment: Does the first column always contain only letters and the second always start with a digit?

Comment: No, It could contain a mix of both in both columns

Comment: Can there be spaces in the second column?

Comment: Yes, there can be spaces in the second column

Comment: What does "similar" mean?

Comment: so I'd have something like ZOOMTEXT MGNFR/RDR SINGLE-USER DOMESTIC, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER/READER SINGLE-USER LICENSE, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER/READER ENTERPRISE, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER/READER - LICENSE - SINGLE USER, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER/READER ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER READER UPGRADE - SINGLE VERSION, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER READER UPGRADE - 3 OR MOVE VERSIONS, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER READER SMA, ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER READER NONENTERPRISE 20-SEATS NETWORK, V.2021
 So the first column over here would appear as ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER READER or ZOOMTEXT MGNFR/RDR or ZOOMTEXT MAGNIFIER/READER

Answer (score 0):

A way might be, but eliminating spaces:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("ABC 123aa", "A BC 456ac", "AB C 789da"))

x <- gsub(" +", "", df$name)
i <- 1
while(length(unique(substr(x, 1, i))) == 1) {
  i <- i+1
  if(any(i > nchar(x))) break;
}

data.frame(name=substr(x, 1, i-1), Type=substring(x, i))
#  name  Type
#1  ABC 123aa
#2  ABC 456ac
#3  ABC 789da
```

or keeping the spaces in the second part:

```
x <- gsub(" +", "", df$name)
i <- 1
while(length(unique(substr(x, 1, i))) == 1) {
  i <- i+1
  if(any(i > nchar(x))) break;
}

y <- substr(x[1], 1, i-1)
data.frame(name=y, Type=sub(paste0("^ *", paste(strsplit(y, "")[[1]], collapse=" *"), " *"), "", df$name))
#  name  Type
#1  ABC 123aa
#2  ABC 456ac
#3  ABC 789da
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it simple

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  Name = c("ABC 123aa", "A BC 456ac", "AB C 789da")
) %>% mutate(
  Type = str_match(Name, "([A-Z, ]{3,5})(\\d{3}.+)")[,3],
  Name = str_match(Name, "([A-Z, ]{3,5})(\\d{3}.+)")[,2] %>% str_replace_all(" ", "")
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Name  Type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 ABC   123aa
2 ABC   456ac
3 ABC   789da
```